# Is it true that the lowest order non-zero contribution for an S matrix element has always to be convergent?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

I was talking with a colleague he told me that if there is no non-zero tree level diagram contributing, then the one loop contribution cannot be divergent. I replied to this saying that this indeed is not true since in the case of the quark current current correlator in QCD the first contribution is at one loop and it is indeed divergent. He told me that he is not concerned about this because and I quote "these are correlators and I don't consider them as diagrams". I think he meant that what he said only applies to S-matrix elements. Nonetheless, I am intrigued, what is the precise statement of the claim he made? That is, is it true that the lowest order non-zero contribution for an S matrix element has always to be convergent? And why is this so? and why is this not the case for correlation functions?

Comment: I think it's the following: an operator generated at one loop that is not allowed at tree-level in a renormalizable lagrangian must be finite since there would be no counter term for it. This is the case for example for the Higgs coupling to photons $|H|^2F_{\mu\nu}^2$ which must be finite since the SM is renormalizable and no counter term would exist for this operator generated at one loop.